# Generate a random digit!

Tags: code-golf, random

Your task is to generate a random digit following these steps:

First, generate 10 random digits to make a binary number, 50% 0, and 50% 1:

```
010011001
```

If it is all zeros, generate a new one.

Convert this to decimal:

```
153
```

For each digit, write that amount of alternating 0s and 1s (first digit = 1s, second digit = 0s, third digit = 1s, etc.):

```
100000111
```

Convert this to decimal:

```
263
```

Take the middle digit (If there is an even number of digits, take the left middle)

```
6
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Do we have to use this algorithm, or does it suffice if the distribution is the same?

Comment: @Pietu1998 If you can prove that the distribution is the same, then OK.

Comment: BTW, your example for 10 digits has 9 digits

Comment: This doesn't actually define a distribution. How should the initial number be generated?

Comment: OK, my previous comment might be due to a misunderstanding. Does the generated number have to consist of five **0**‘s and five **1**'s or should **0**‘s and **1**'s follow a u iform distribution?

Comment: Hmm good point @Dennis, reading between the lines I think the latter, since otherwise we never get to "If it is all zeros".

Comment: What do you mean by the second "convert this to decimal" - isn't `100000111` converted to decimal `263`?

Comment: I don't know why I even bother anymore, because you clearly don't listen... Use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/45941)!

Comment: Can we assume our random generator is uniform?

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*1 byte thanks to @Jakube (swap `r` operands).*

```
ehc2`ir9,R=!ZjOS1023T2
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ehc2%60ir9%2CR%3D%21ZjOS1023T2&test_suite=1&debug=0)

> First, generate 10 random digits to make a binary number, 50% 0, and 50% 1.
> If it is all zeros, generate a new one.
> Convert this to decimal.

Generate a number between 1 and 1023. `OS1023` in Pyth. Then get its digits: `j`…`T`.

> For each digit, write that amount of alternating 0s and 1s (first digit = 1s, second digit = 0s, third digit = 1s, etc.).

Pair each digit with an alternating `True` or `False`: `,R=!Z`. The alternating booleans come from `=!Z`, or `Z = not Z` where `Z` starts as 0. Then run-length decode: `r`…`9`.

> Convert this to decimal.

Parse integer as binary: `i`…`2`.

> Take the middle digit (If there is an even number of digits, take the left middle).

Take the string representation: `` ` ``. Split it in two, with the possible middle character going to the left: `c2`. Take the first half's last character: `eh`.

Comment: `r9...` instead of `r...9`

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>62</s> <s>61</s> <s>55</s> 53 bytes

Get the digit distribution through a lookup table. Implementing the original algorithm is about 15 bytes longer.

```
perl -E 'say-(map+(--$n)x$_,unpack"W*","\x90leJZaEC_")[rand 1023]'
```

Just the code:

```
say-(map+(--$n)x$_,unpack"W*","\x90leJZaEC_")[rand 1023]
```

Works as shown,, but replace `\x90` by the literal byte to get the claimed score

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
To<L.RvTNèy×}JC2ä¬¤
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VG88TC5SdlROw6h5w5d9SkMyw6TCrMKk&input=)

**Explanation**

`153` used as example

```
To<L                  # [1 ... 2^10-1]
                      # STACK: [1 ... 1023]
    .R                # take random number from range
                      # STACK: 153                          
      v     }         # for each digit
       TNè            # use the digits index in the number to index into 10 
          y×          # repeat the number that many times 
                      # STACK: 1,00000,111
             J        # join to string
                      # STACK: 100000111
              C       # convert to decimal
                      # STACK: 263
               2ä     # split in 2
                      # STACK: [26,3]
                 ¬¤   # take the last digits of the first part
                      # OUTPUT: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁵Ḷx“ḶƇleJZaEC_‘µX
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oG14bi2eOKAnOG4tsaHbGVKWmFFQ1_igJjCtVg&input=)**

#### How?

The distribution of the first step are [1,1023] with equal likelihood.
Applying the transformation instructed for each of those numbers produces a distribution of:
`{0: 178, 1: 144, 2: 108, 3: 101, 4: 74, 5: 90, 6: 97, 7: 69, 8: 67, 9: 95}`

```
⁵Ḷx“ḶƇleJZaEC_‘µX - Main link: (niladic)
⁵                 - literal 10
 Ḷ                - range -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   “ḶƇleJZaEC_‘   - code page indexes -> [178,144,108,101,74,90,97,69,67,95]
  x               - repeat - > [178 zeros, 144 ones, 108 twos, ...]
               µ  - monadic chain separation
                X - pick a random element
```